# Retrieving the list elements using xpath in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to selenium xpath and here's a code I tried. It doesn't enter the loop at all. I think the paths are right. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="one"]/ul/li')
for li in a:
     xval =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('.div/text()')`
```

```html
<div class="one">
 <ul>
  <li><div id="1">Hi</div></li> 
  <li><div id="2"> Hello</div></li> 
  <li><div id="3">Bye</div></li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search child element by querying parent element. Also check the length of the parent element, does it have anything?

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="one"]/ul/li')
print len(a)
for li in a:
     xval =  li.find_element_by_xpath('div/text()')
```

Answer (score 1):

In `selenium` `find_element_by_xpath()` method should return `WebElement`, but not text content.

Try to replace

```
xval = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.div/text()')
```

with

```
xval = driver.find_element_by_xpath('./div').text
```

Also note that you should use `./div` instead of `.div` to match `div` that is direct child of current element

*Update*

If your loop make no iteration try to wait until required `div` appears in `DOM` as it might be generated dynamically:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By. XPATH, "//div[@class="one" and ./ul/li])))
```

Comment: Thank you. I made those changes. But it doesn't enter the loop in the first place. Why is that ?